# how to set maximum width for splitview?

Tags: cocoa, nssplitview

I am new to Cocoa and Xcode 4. I have one project on OSX Lion Application. I need to design interface in Xcode. I use `NSSplitView` to create 3 column in my Application. And i want to set the maximum size for the first column and the third column but I don't know how to do and where to find it. Could anyone give me some detail example or step by step.